# My string compare functions returns false even though the string is in the array

Tags: arrays, c, char, strcmp

for the following code when I search for top hat I am not getting the desired result(i.e found)
Instead the output is not found.
I assume it is to do with how the char arrays are working behind the scenes, can anyone explain this to me.

```
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LIMIT 20

int main(void)
{
    char strin[MAX_LIMIT];
    char numbers[6][10] = {"battleship","boat","cannon","iron","thimble","top hat"};
    printf("enter string to search:");
    scanf("%s", &strin);

    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(numbers[i],strin)==0)
        {
            printf("found\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("not found\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: The string `"top hat"` canot be read with format spec `%s`, which stops at the first whitespace character. I suggest you use `scanf(" %19[^\n]", strin);`. Note too that the `&` should not be used in `scanf` before `strin`.

Comment: What is the value of `strin` after a call to `scanf()` reports success?

Comment: in that case how would I read this if not with s?

Comment: Please refresh your browser page.

Comment: If you want to read lines, use `fgets()` rather than `scanf()`.

Comment: But you must also see [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input/28462221#28462221)

Comment: ahhh it worked, but what exactly happened there? I have not seen this before

Comment: Which one worked? What haven't you seen?

Comment: using %19[^\n] worked but what does this expression mean, I am going through the other way of using fgets

Comment: Please refer to the `scanf` man pages written for your education! It's all quite detailed, so I suggest you spend some time reading with hands-on examples and tests.

Comment: There's also a pretty good summary of `scanf`s format string [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). See what it says about `s` and about `[set]`.

Comment: `"battleship"` requires 11 characters in order to be properly terminated. The array is too small.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` in `scanf("%s", &strin);` will read data from stdin until a whitespace character occurs.

As such, when you type into "top hat", `scanf` will read `top` not `top hat`.

I ran your code,value of `strin` was `top`. There is not such string in numbers.

`strin` is an array of char.The name of an char array is memory address.I think using `strin` instead of `&strin` is better.

If I want to search "top hat" in numbers,I will use `fgets` instead of `scanf`.Here is my code.It works well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LIMIT 20

int main(void)
{
    char strin[MAX_LIMIT];
    char numbers[6][10] = {"battleship","boat","cannon","iron","thimble","top hat"};
    printf("enter string to search:");
//    scanf("%5s", &strin);
    fgets(strin, sizeof(strin), stdin);
    strin[strcspn(strin, "\n")] = '\0';


    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(numbers[i],strin)==0)
        {
            printf("found\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("not found\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try searching for "battleship", then try "battleshipboat", then change `numbers[6][10]` to `numbers[6][11]`.

Comment: Changing `char numbers[6][10] = {"battleship","boat","cannon","iron","thimble","top hat"};` to `char *numbers[6] = {"battleship","boat","cannon","iron","thimble","top hat"};` will be better.

Comment: Depends on the use. In this case I would say `const char *numbers[6] = {...}` is the most appropriate, but if modification of the values is desired then the 2d array wins, as long as the extents are correct.

Comment: Good.I agree with you.